# google app script hiding row with specific range only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function hideRows2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var r = s.getRange("D:D");
  var v = r.getValues();
  var h = new Array();
  var count = 0;
  s.unhideRow(r);
  var firstRow = 6;
  for(var i=firstRow-1;i<v.length;i++) {
    if( v[i][0]=="" )
      count=count+1;
    if( i >= v.length-1 || v[i+1][0]!="" ) {
      if(count>0)
        h.push([i+2-count,count]);
      count=0;
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<h.length;i++)
    s.hideRows(h[i][0],h[i][1]);
};
```

How can I hide row from row 6 till row 21 only the current script hide row from row 6 till end row if column D is an empty cell.

Currently, the script works fine but I cannot hide the row below row 21.

Comment: show what code you are using and its current and required output ?

Comment: hi @NitinSingh  hi  the output that i want is to be able to hide row in  between row 6 and row 21 if columnD is an empty cell ...  the current script works fine but it run all the row below row 6

Comment: Change v.length to 21 and see if that helps?

Comment: I recommend rewriting this from scratch, since your goal has changed drastically. For example, this code checks all values in column D, while your new requirement is it to check rows 6 through 21. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object has two methods:

```
hideRow(rowIndex)
```

and

```
hideRows(rowIndex, numRows)
```

I'd say your loop should use hideRow() to hide the individual rows instead of calling hideRows to hide more than 1.